# Is possible to initiate a app from another in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I'm would like initiate another app which is listed in my app when user touch that app. is it possible? help me howto do that?

Comment: no you cant if you try your app will be rejected as this the violation of your app trying to access another app or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly possible - the only way you can execute another application is via a URL handler.

For example, you can open a page in Safari via:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"]];
```

And you get place a call (albeit with the user's agreement) via:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://xxxx"]];
```

As such, it really depends on whether on the the application you wish to open has registered a URL handler.

Answer (score 1):

With a custom URL handler, registered by the destination application, this should be possible.

http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2009/03/building-services-into-iphone-applications.ars

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Usually it is used to launch a few iPhone APIs such as Phone, Mail, Map, YouTube. 
But you can use that for launching your own App that have implemented Apple URL Scheme http://www.docstoc.com/docs/3595962/iPhone-URL-Scheme. The idee is that you should create URL with some parameters for app wich you want to launch, and run it. Good luck.